# How can I set OMS alerts for API Management Services

Tags: azure

I am trying to set some OMS alerts for API management services, but I am unable to set the alerts for API management services, as there is no solutions in solutions gallery in OMS, I have enabled the diagnostics (Send to log analytics), but cant figure out how to set any of the alerts. Can anyone correct me on this or guide me.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show [the code you have so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include at least an outline (but preferably a [mcve]) of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Answer (score 0):

Just like you would do with any other alert:

1. From the OMS Overview page, click Log Search.
2. Either create a new log search query or select a saved log search.
3. Click Alert at the top of the page to open the Add Alert Rule screen.
4. Configure the alert rule using information in Details of alert rules below.
5. Click Save to complete the alert rule. It will start running immediately.

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/log-analytics/log-analytics-alerts-creating

Comment: The thing is I cant seam to find the log for api management services can you give me any example that I would place in my search log.

Comment: Type=AzureMetrics ResourceId="Microsoft.ApiManagement"    I am trying this in log search But I couldnt get any results